# Communicate from class to parent class?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an `Account` class in my app which is a user's bank account. This initialises two classes called `Withdrawals` and `Deposits`. They look like this:

**Account.h**

```
@interface Account : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSInteger *amount;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Withdrawal *withdrawal;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Deposit *deposit;

- (id)initWithAmount:(NSInteger *)amount;

- (Withdrawal *)withdrawal;
- (Deposit *)deposit;

@end
```

**Account.m**

```
@implementation Account

- (id)initWithAmount:(NSInteger *)amount {
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        _amount = amount;
        _withdrawal = [[Withdrawal alloc] init];
        _deposit = [[Deposit alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (Withdrawal *)withdrawal {
    return _withdrawal;
}

- (Deposit *)deposit {
    return _deposit;
}

@end
```

Ideally, what I'd like to is to be able to call `[[account withdrawal] withdraw:50]` and have `[account amount]` be updated as well. What's the best way to tackle this?

Comment: @vadian You're right. I rewrote the example to better match the actual code in my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First it is very unlikely that `amount` should have type `NSInteger *`, that is a *pointer to an* integer, it is far more likely that it should simply be `NSInteger`, that is an integer. Same goes for all other uses of `NSInteger *`. This is because `amount` is an *value* and not a *reference to an object*, unlike say you `withdrawal` property which returns a reference to an object.

> Ideally, what I'd like to is to be able to call `[[account withdrawal] withdraw:50]` and have `[account amount]` be updated as well. What's the best way to tackle this?

Without commenting on the design, if your withdrawal object needs to access your account object then it needs a (way to obtain a) reference to it. You should think in terms of a `Withdrawal` class have in a property of its associated `Account`, just as your `Account` has a property of its associated `Withdrawal`. You might for instance set this when creating the `Withdrawal` object, where your current:

```
_withdrawal = [[Withdrawal alloc] init];
```

becomes:

```
_withdrawal = [[Withdrawal alloc] initWithAccount:self];
```

Doing this may cause you to create a cycle - every `Account` instance references a `Withdrawal` instance, which in turns references the `Account` instance. Cycles *per se* are not bad, they only become bad if they prevent unwanted objects from being collected. However I suspect your `Account` will end up with a `closeAccount` method, which is where you can break any cycles as needed.

Hopefully that will give you something to go away and work on. If you find your design/code doesn't work ask a new question detailing what you've designed & coded and what your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

This is a composition relation not a child-parent one. To get the actual left amount of account you can rewrite the `amount`'s getter:

```
- (NSInteger)amount {
   _amount = // set left amount, this value should come from Withdrawal class 
   return _amount;
}
```

Btw, remove `*` from NSInteger instance, make it a simple integer value not a pointer.